Images from public directory is not getting in my Laravel Project
I am quite new to laravel (VILT) stack. I am using Spatie's media library to upload and retrieve images. My codes are working fine.
Image is uploading and storing on media table by spatie's media library, even I am getting the uploaded image url via this function:
$companyLogo = $jobDetail->getFirstMediaUrl('companyLogo');

// OutputUrl = http://localhost/storage/9/dummy-customer.jpg

I confirmed that image is there, but it's not getting from browser. 
I'd appreciate if you could give me some clue on it.
